# JSR-303 custom annotation

Tags: java, validation, annotations, hibernate-validator

I'm trying to implement a custom annotation to validate my fields. The idea is that the validation fails whenever the annotated field is `null`. Something like this.

```
@RequiredProperty
public abstract Person getPerson();
```

Now if this returns a `null` Person, I'd like the validation to fail (ideally with a custom message "Person field is null").

I tried to do it like this.

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = RequiredPropertyValidator.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, ANNOTATION_TYPE, TYPE_USE})
@ReportAsSingleViolation
public @interface RequiredProperty {

    String message() default "{javax.validation.constraints.RequiredProperty.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

And validator.

```
public class RequiredPropertyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<RequiredProperty, Object> {


    @Override
    public void initialize(RequiredProperty constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object property, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return property != null;
    }
}
```

However this won't work. It doesn't validate at all. Object `property` is never even passed to the `isValid` method. Any advice on how to get it working?

**UPDATE**

Removing the empty `initialize` method got it working. However, I'm not sure how to create a custom error message that the "Person" field is null. Is that possible?

I created a custom message in `.properties` file, but this is just a static message, and I'd like to capture the actual field from runtime.

Comment: Do you have any specific reason not to use the standard @NotNull annotation?

Comment: Also it would be useful if you post a sample of your code that is trying to use this annotation

Comment: Please see update.

Comment: @user2612030 Yes, AutoValue throws exception with it if the field is null.